# sequelize duplicated foreignKey on 1:m association

Tags: mysql, database, foreign-keys, associations, sequelize.js

I have a database that contains announcements and users.

users can create many announcements, while an announcement is created by only one user.

to define this using sequelize I did this :

the announcements model :

```
    'use strict';
module.exports = function (sequelize, DataTypes) {
    var announcement = sequelize.define('announcements', {
        id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            primaryKey: true,
            autoIncrement: true
        },
        title: DataTypes.STRING,
        description: DataTypes.TEXT,
        likes: DataTypes.INTEGER
    }, {
        classMethods: {
            associate: function (models) {
                /**
                 * an announcement is created by only one user
                 */
                announcement.belongsTo(models.users, {
                  as: 'Owner'
                });
            }
        }
    });
    return announcement;
}
```

the users model :

```
'use strict';
module.exports = function (sequelize, DataTypes) {
    var users = sequelize.define('users', {
        id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            primaryKey: true
        },
        username: {
          type: DataTypes.STRING,
          unique: true
        },
        email: {
          type: DataTypes.STRING,
          unique: true,
          validate: {
            isEmail: true
          }
        }
    }, {
        timestamps: true,
        classMethods: {
            associate: function (models) {
                /**
                 * a user has many announcements
                 */
                users.hasMany(models.announcements, {
                    as: 'Announcements',
                    foreingKey: {
                        name: 'id',
                        allowNull: false
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
    return users;
};
```

after running the app I find duplicated userid (OwnerId and userId) in the announcements database. it must be only one 'OwnerId'.

so what is the thing that I did wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem : I misspelled "foreignKey" and wrote it as "foreingKey". now everything is ok